# android studio Cannot resolve symbol AppCompatActivity

Tags: android-studio, обновление, android-gradle

После обновления Android Studio с версии 3.1.3 до 3.1.4 появилась ошибка (подчеркивание красным цветом) при наведении на некоторые классы, а именно - `Cannot resolve symbol`.

Подчеркивались такие классы как `android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate;`, `android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;`, `android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;`

Следующие решения не помогли:

1. `File` -> `Invalidate Cashes / Restart...`
2. `File` -> `Sync with File System`
3. `File` -> `Sync Project with Gradle Files`
4. `Build` -> `Clean Project`
5. `Build` -> `Rebuild Project`

Возможно ли как-то решить проблему?

Answer (score 1):

Помогла информация по следующей [ссылке](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6TlLDU4UuhQ). (*Содержание вопроса перекликается с содержимым по ссылке, но сути это не меняет, проблема появилась - упомянутые шаги не помогали - проблема решилась*)

Решение:

1. `File` -> `Export to Zip File...` Сохраняем проект в новом расположении (без кирилицы в пути). Распаковываем.
2. Закрываем текущий проект. В стартовом окне Android Studio выбираем `Open an existing Android Studio Project` и загружаем распакованный проект из нового расположения
3. В окошке отображается процесс `Building "..." Gradle project info`
4. Появляется новое окошко `Android Gradle Plugin Update Recommended`. Выбираем `Update`